# Could not find the Qt platform plugin "wasm" in "" – building Qt with Emscripten (Bazel)

Tags: qt, bazel, webassembly, emscripten

This has turned out to be quite a journey so I'll start with the the reproduction recipe. There is no doubt that somebody will answer this in 2 minutes given how unfamiliar I'm with emscripten and Qt.

To create my app, I'm modifying the emscripten bazel example
https://github.com/emscripten-core/emsdk/tree/main/bazel

The Qt is pre-compiled locally so I added a `new_local_repository` to the `WORKSPACE` file

```
new_local_repository(
    name = "qt-everywhere",
    path = ".../emsdk-2.0.26/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.5",
    build_file = "vendor/qt-everywhere.BUILD",
)
```

The `vendor/qt-everywhere.BUILD` looks like this

```
package(default_visibility = ['//visibility:public'])

cc_library(
  name = "all",
  hdrs = glob(["include/*/**"]),
  srcs = glob(["lib/*.a"]) + glob(["plugins/*/*.a"])  + glob(["lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/*.cpp"]),
  includes = [
    "include",
    "include/QtAccessibilitySupport",
    "include/QtCore",
    "include/QtDeviceDiscoverySupport",
    "include/QtEdidSupport",
    "include/QtEglSupport",
    "include/QtEventDispatcherSupport",
    "include/QtFbSupport",
    "include/QtFontDatabaseSupport",
    "include/qtfreetype",
    "include/QtGui",
    "include/qtharfbuzz",
    "include/qtlibjpeg",
    "include/qtlibpng",
    "include/QtNetwork",
    "include/QtOpenGL",
    "include/QtOpenGLExtensions",
    "include/QtPlatformCompositorSupport",
    "include/QtPlatformHeaders",
    "include/QtPrintSupport",
    "include/QtServiceSupport",
    "include/QtSvg",
    "include/QtTest",
    "include/QtThemeSupport",
    "include/QtWidgets",
    "include/QtXml",
    "include/QtZlib",
  ],
)
```

The part that's broken is the plugins, compiled from the .cpp files above but we'll get to that later.

I've modified the `hello-world.cc` to look like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  new QHBoxLayout();
  std::cout << "hello world!" << std::endl;
  QApplication application(argc, argv);
  return application.exec();
  // return 0;
}
```

And finally my `BUILD` file is modified to tie it all together

```
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_binary")
load("//emscripten_toolchain:wasm_rules.bzl", "wasm_cc_binary")

cc_binary(
    name = "hello-world",
    srcs = ["hello-world.cc"],
    deps = [
        "@qt-everywhere//:all",
    ],
    linkopts = [
        "--oformat=html", "-s", "MINIFY_HTML=0"
    ],
)

wasm_cc_binary(
    name = "hello-world-wasm",
    cc_target = ":hello-world",
)
```

And to build I issue this command

```
bazel build --verbose_failures //hello-world:hello-world-wasm
```

There is no error on output

```
bazel build --verbose_failures //hello-world:hello-world-wasm
INFO: Analyzed target //hello-world:hello-world-wasm (207 packages loaded, 16785 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
INFO: From Linking hello-world/hello-world:
emcc: warning: external/qt-everywhere/lib/libQt5Bootstrap.a: archive is missing an index; Use emar when creating libraries to ensure an index is created [-Wemcc]
emcc: warning: external/qt-everywhere/lib/libQt5Bootstrap.a: adding index [-Wemcc]
Target //hello-world:hello-world-wasm up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/hello-world/hello-world-wasm/hello-world.js
  bazel-bin/hello-world/hello-world-wasm/hello-world.wasm
  bazel-bin/hello-world/hello-world-wasm/hello-world.wasm.map
  bazel-bin/hello-world/hello-world-wasm/hello-world.js.mem
  bazel-bin/hello-world/hello-world-wasm/hello-world.fetch.js
  bazel-bin/hello-world/hello-world-wasm/hello-world.worker.js
  bazel-bin/hello-world/hello-world-wasm/hello-world.data
  bazel-bin/hello-world/hello-world-wasm/hello-world.js.symbols
  bazel-bin/hello-world/hello-world-wasm/hello-world.wasm.debug.wasm
  bazel-bin/hello-world/hello-world-wasm/hello-world.html
INFO: Elapsed time: 102.326s, Critical Path: 96.78s
INFO: 14 processes: 3 internal, 11 darwin-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 14 total actions
➜  bazel git:(main) ✗
```

Here is how the outputs look like

```
ls -la bazel-bin/hello-world/hello-world-wasm/
total 18632
drwxr-xr-x  12 .  wheel      384 Sep 12 10:23 .
drwxr-xr-x   7 .  wheel      224 Sep 12 10:20 ..
-r-xr-xr-x   1 .  wheel        0 Sep 12 10:23 hello-world.data
-r-xr-xr-x   1 .  wheel        0 Sep 12 10:23 hello-world.fetch.js
-r-xr-xr-x   1 .  wheel   102681 Sep 12 10:23 hello-world.html
-r-xr-xr-x   1 .  wheel   119196 Sep 12 10:23 hello-world.js
-r-xr-xr-x   1 .  wheel        0 Sep 12 10:23 hello-world.js.mem
-r-xr-xr-x   1 .  wheel        0 Sep 12 10:23 hello-world.js.symbols
-r-xr-xr-x   1 .  wheel  9309260 Sep 12 10:23 hello-world.wasm
-r-xr-xr-x   1 .  wheel        0 Sep 12 10:23 hello-world.wasm.debug.wasm
-r-xr-xr-x   1 .  wheel        0 Sep 12 10:23 hello-world.wasm.map
-r-xr-xr-x   1 .  wheel        0 Sep 12 10:23 hello-world.worker.js
```

The error appears as soon as I attempt to run the app in the browser, in the browser console

```
python3 -m http.server -d bazel-bin/hello-world/hello-world-wasm
emrun --browser=chrome bazel-bin/hello-world/hello-world-wasm
```

The browser console then shows

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "wasm" in ""
printErr @ hello-world.html:1246
hello-world.html:1246 This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
printErr @ hello-world.html:1246
```

### Solution 1 - copy the Qt5Gui .cpp files

The solution turned out to be quite tricky: the files from "lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/*.cpp" have to be copied into the source directory and compiled along with the `hello-world` binary target.

The BUILD file becomes something like

```
cc_binary(
    name = "hello-world",
    srcs = ["hello-world.cc"] + glob(["Qt5Gui_*.cpp"]),
    deps = [
        "@qt-everywhere//:all",
    ],
    linkopts = [
        "--oformat=html", "-s", "MINIFY_HTML=0"
    ],
)
```

### Solution 2 - cc_library with alwayslink=True

This is the alternative, ensures that symbols from "lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/*.cpp" are always exposed, even when not used directly. That behavior is needed because these symbols will be called at runtime by WASM, changing `vendor/qt-everywhere.BUILD`.

```
cc_library(
  name = "all",
  hdrs = glob(["include/*/**"]),
  srcs = glob(["lib/*.a"]) + glob(["plugins/*/*.a"]) + glob(["lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/*.cpp"]),
  includes = ["include/"] + glob(["include/*"], exclude_directories=0),
  alwayslink = True,
)
```

Comment: Running into the same problem and finding very little information on how to fix it. Is there still no better solution than this?